# Write a semi-custom deserializer

Tags: spring, jackson

I would like to write a Custom Deserialization component that would still use some of the default capabilities:

Imagine those classes:

```java
class Category {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

class Article {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Category category;
}
```

And this JSON payload:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Pray for Notre Dame",
  "category_id": 5
}
```

With my understanding of the various articles I read online, I should write a custom deserializer to handle my `category_id` field:

```java
@JsonComponent
public class ArticleJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Article> {

    @Override
    public Article deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, 
      DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, 
      JsonProcessingException {

        TreeNode treeNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        TextNode category = this.entityManager.getReference(Category.class, treeNode.get("category_id"));

        // The following lines bother me
        String title = treeNode.get("title");
        Long id = treeNode.get("id");

        return new Article(id, title, category);
    }
}
```

**However, in reality, I would love to use the default deserializer capabilities for the `title` and `id` fields without rewriting this logic.**

How can I do that?

Comment: Yes, it is an Article sorry. I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Assuming that you have a default constructor in the `Article` class, the following should work:

```java
Article article = jsonParser.getCodec().treeToValue(treeNode, Article.class);
```

Then set the `category` in the `article`.

### A bit longer answer

Well... I think you are cutting corners and going beyond of what custom deserializers are meant for. You probably don't want to create couplings like that.

Alternatively, you could use [`@JsonIdentityInfo`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html) along with an [`ObjectIdResolver`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/ObjectIdResolver.html). You could get some ideas from the approach described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42146080/1426227).

Instead of exposing your JPA entities in your web API, you could using consider DTOs. See the reasons I described in my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175349/1426227) for reference. And then you could have a mapping layer to map your entities to your DTOs and vice versa. If you are using [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/), for example, the documentation [shows an example](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#passing-target-type) on how to resolve entities by their id.

Comment: Alright, so if I want to follow best practices, should I take the the raw request body in the controller parameters and send this to a service that would handle such a deserialization? (I validate the answer because it actually seems to respond to my question but I would be very happy to have your input on this as I'm a new user of spring)

Comment: @Hammerbot I've added some details to my answer. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! I'm definitely going to use DTO'S because I feel comfortable with this principle! Have a nice day!