# Spring unresolved forward reference in Many to One

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

I have a task and a user entity, with a one-to-many relationship.
So in english a user can have multiple tasks, and a task belongs to a single user

```
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="task")
    private Set<Task> tasks;
}
```

```
public class Task {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    @JsonProperty("user_id")
    private User user;
    private String name;
}
```

When i try to POST a task with

```
{
  "name": "Test task",
  "user_id": 1
}
```

i get the following:

```
Unresolved forward references for: ; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference
```

**EDIT:**
Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007188/deserialize-json-with-spring-unresolved-forward-references-jackson-exception) and implementing an EntityIdResolver returns in this error:

```
 Unable to locate persister: java.lang.Object; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unable to locate persister
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON with spring : Unresolved forward references Jackson Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007188/deserialize-json-with-spring-unresolved-forward-references-jackson-exception)

Comment: @SternK kinda. Now it throws: Unable to locate persister: java.lang.Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and bind an object implementing [`ObjectIdResolver`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/ObjectIdResolver.html) with autowired `EntityManager`. **Jackson is clueless otherwise how to find the correct entity**, since there is no relationship between the ORM implementation and de/serialization library in this case.

This resolver itself is:

> Definition of API used for resolving actual Java object from Object Identifiers (as annotated using JsonIdentityInfo).

The key method is [`ObjectIdResolver::resolveId`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/ObjectIdResolver.html#resolveId-com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerator.IdKey-) where you get the item to be matched by its ID using the following method:

- [`EntityManager::find(Class<T> entityClass, Object primaryKey)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-)

Sample code:

```
@Override
public Object resolveId(final ObjectIdGenerator.IdKey id) {
    return entityManager.find(id.scope, id.key);
}
```

The resolver shall be used then with `@JsonIdentityInfo`:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
    property="id", 
    resolver = CustomIdResolver.class)
...
private User user;
```

This question might help as well: [JsonIdentityInfo Resolver instantiated in Spring Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203808/jsonidentityinfo-resolver-instantiated-in-spring-context)